# Angular JS boostrap modal window, on ok() saveEvent and update event list of the parent scope

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, promise

**The scenario is trivial:**

1. User opens modal window.
2. User enters event name(event in this case is domain related event such as "meeting" or "match").
3. Event is saved on ok (`ok()` -> 'save' rest call to backend).
4. When event is successfully created another call to backend is made to retrieve updated list of events.

Problem: I don't understand how I strictly synchronize the flow where after the event is saved the modal window is closed and after modal window is closed the event list updated.

**Update: After more testing I notice race condition, sometimes new event appears sometimes not.**

After repeatedly trying to return back to angular for roughly 2 years I am again stuck on promises.

What I have at the moment is after I call `ok()` the event is saved and the modal window is dismissed but the list of events of dashboard is not updated. When I create new event again, the result is that I see the updated list with previously created event on my dashboard but not the one I just created...

```
app.controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModal, $log, eventService) {
    console.log("ModalDemoCtrl Controller Loaded.");
    $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

    $scope.animationsEnabled = true;

    $scope.open = function (size) {

        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
            templateUrl: 'eventModal.html',
            controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
            size: size,
            resolve: {
                items: function () {
                    return $scope.items;
                }
            }
        });

        modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
            $scope.selected = selectedItem;

            eventService.getEvents().success(function (data) {
                $log.info("Received number of events:" + data.length);
                $scope.$parent.events = data;
            }).error(function (status) {
                $log.info("Error with status: " + status);
            });
        }, function () {
            $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
        });
    };

    $scope.toggleAnimation = function () {
        $scope.animationsEnabled = !$scope.animationsEnabled;
    };

});

// Please note that $modalInstance represents a modal window (instance) dependency.
// It is not the same as the $uibModal service used above.

app.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, items, eventService, $log) {
    console.log("ModalInstanceCtrl Controller Loaded.");
    $scope.items = items;
    $scope.selected = {
        item: $scope.items[0]
    };

    $scope.ok = function (event) {
        eventService.saveEvent(event).success(function (data) {
            console.log("savedEvent")
        }).error(function (status) {

        });

        $uibModalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);

    };

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you do it to avoid the race condition...

In your modal controller (`ModalInstanceCtrl`), what you want to do is save your event via your service and **then** close the modal, resolving the `result` with your new event

```
$scope.ok = function (event) {
    eventService.saveEvent(event).success(function (data) {
        console.log("savedEvent");
        $uibModalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
    }).error(function (status) {
        // you might want to dismiss the modal here, it's up to you
    });
};
```

Also, you can cut down on controller code by using `$uibModalInstance` methods directly in your `eventModal.html` template

```
<button type="button" ng-click="$dismiss('cancel')">Cancel</button>
```

Comment: thanks, I completely overlooked this piece, but there is also eventService.getEvents()  which does not guarantee to return the list of events before the modal closes and update scope in time.

Comment: @Aubergine seeing as you only run `getEvents` in the `modalInstance.result.then` promise, you are guaranteed that it will run only after your new event is persisted (using the code in my answer) as that promise is resolve by calling `$uibModalInstance.close`

Comment: You are 100 % right, after moving into the success block it consistently returns the events. I didn't even understand where the problem was , sigh... So before getEvents was called in time but was setting the scope before the saveEvent returned.

Comment: @Aubergine exactly. Whilst the `saveEvent` was working (asynchronously), you had already closed the modal and attempted to fetch the events again via `getEvents`